# SQL Server - Struggling to group/sum values across multiple related tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT 
    g.PartNum,
    g.Supplier,
    (g.InitialQuantityToInventory + SUM(COALESCE(t.AmountInventoryAdjusted + t.AmountReturned, 0))) AS StockLevel
FROM 
    GoodsIn g
LEFT JOIN 
    Transfers t ON g.GoodsInNumber = t.GoodsInNumber
WHERE 
    g.PartNum = '123'
GROUP BY 
    g.PartNum, g.Supplier, g.InitialQuantityToInventory
```

And it's returns these results:

```
123,SUP1,67
123,NULL,18
123,NULL,0
123,NULL,45
123,NULL,0
```

However I would like the `StockLevel` (in the 3rd column) to `SUM` on the supplier name, even when it's null, so that my expected result should be:

```
123,SUP1,67
123,NULL,63
```

What am I doing wrong? The query should (across all GoodsIn Numbers that have the same PartNumber & Supplier) Sum the InitialQuantities and their Amounts Adjusted & Returned for each transfer associated with the GoodsIn record.

This is the data for that part & supplier in the GoodsIn Table:

```
GINum  Part Num    Supplier InitialQuantityToInventory
73367   123        NULL     81    
73570   123        NULL     18
74154   123        NULL     320
74835   123        Sup1     0
74836   123        NULL     500
75738   123        Sup1     0
```

And this is the corresponding rows from the Transfers table (T being short for TransferNum):

```
GINum      T    Adj    Ret
73367      1    -81    0
74154      1    -200   0
74154      2    -120   45
74835      1    67     0
74836      1    -500   0
75738      1    -300   0
75738      2    300    0
```

Comment: It looks like that GoodsIn table is a log style table and you have a data / normalisation issue with your join. Your initial query results are likely incorrect. If they are correct, then the easiest way to solve this is add another GROUP BY around your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to not group by InitialQuantityToInventory?

```
;WITH Logs (Supplier, Initial, StockChange)
AS
(
SELECT
    g.Supplier,
    g.InitialQuantityToInventory,
    (SUM(COALESCE(t.AmountInventoryAdjusted  + t.AmountReturned,0))) AS StockChange
FROM
    GoodsIn g
LEFT JOIN
    Transfers t ON g.GoodsInNumber = t.GoodsId
GROUP BY
    g.Supplier, g.InitialQuantityToInventory
)

SELECT 
    Supplier,
    SUM(Initial) + SUM(StockChange) AS StockLevel
 FROM
    Logs
GROUP BY
    Supplier
```

What might be happening is you're getting a row per unique InitialQuantityToInventory, but from what I gather, you want these to be summed, right?

This could probably be optimised further (and probably doesn't need a CTE), but hopefully it at least returns the data you expect.

Comment: SQL Server was insisting I added InitialQuantityToInventory to the GROUP BY clause. That's grouped the NULL Suppliers, but i'm now getting a summed result of 383 for that row, when it should be 63? The InitialQuantity for the NULL suppliers has been summed correctly, but the Amounts have been summed incorrectly.

Comment: See my edit @JohnBergqvist - does that return what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to `GROUP BY InitialQuantityToInventory`. Try following query and let me know if this works for what you need.

```
SELECT
    g.PartNum,
    g.Supplier,
    MAX(g.InitialQuantityToInventory) + SUM(COALESCE(t.AmountInventoryAdjusted + t.AmountReturned,0)) AS StockLevel
FROM
    GoodsIn g
LEFT JOIN
    Transfers t ON g.GoodsInNumber = t.GoodsInNumber
WHERE
    g.PartNum = '123'
GROUP BY
    g.PartNum, g.Supplier
```

Comment: That's not working either. Again, the value with the Supplier name is correct, However the NULL supplier's stock level is -353. I think maybe it's not taking into account either the PartName when it sums the AmountInventoryAdjusted values. I've updated the OP with what's actually in the tables i'm trying to get from (for that Part & Supplier).

Comment: can u show the exact data on which you are writing this query on?

Comment: I think the problem is that my SUM(g.InitialQuantityToInventory) line is giving me a different value to what it is when I add the 4 rows up by hand. This appears to occur as soon as I create the join to the Transfers table, the SUM result is now 1239 instead of 919...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, group the Transfers before joining and grouping

```
SELECT
    g.PartNum,
    g.Supplier,
    SUM(g.InitialQuantityToInventory + COALESCE(t.adjRet, 0))
FROM Goodsin g
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT GINum, SUM(AmountInventoryAdjusted + AmountReturned) AS adjRet
        FROM Transfers
        GROUP BY GINum
    ) T
    ON t.GINum = g.GiNum
GROUP BY g.PartNum,    g.Supplier
```

Comment: Thanks! Both yours & evilbhonda's solution worked :)